# Xorg Session crashes my XPS 15

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, dell, xps

I have an issue that you guys might be able to help me fix. I have received a all new XPS 15 yesterday, and installed Ubuntu 17.10 on it.

It currently work like a charm with Wayland. I have the proprietary drivers installed and bumblebee to help me have a decent battery life!

The issue I have is that I am unable to login in a Xorg session. Wayland is nice but there is some softwares that I need that requires to run on Xorg.....

So what happens is that I change the session in GDM3 to Ubuntu On Xorg and then nothing happens. The mouse is frozen. Well, the laptop just freezes. It feels like I have nouveau installed or that is being loaded for some reasons. It is weird cause nouveau is blacklisted and I have added the following parameter to my grub: `nouveau.modeset=0` which helped me boot in the live disk when I wanted to install Ubuntu yesterday.

This is my `lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
```

Thank you guys! Don't be shy ask me for more details if it is needed!

Comment: Forgot to mention earlier, please don't add "Solved" to the title. Instead, you can mark an answer as "Accepted", which will essentially mark the question as "Solved"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem

I used theses resources to fix my issues:

- https://gist.github.com/whizzzkid/37c0d365f1c7aa555885d102ec61c048
- https://gist.github.com/parasquid/5cbfb9a8f4159b546ab8b2ef2328d942
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560

First of all, my problem was related to bumblebee, which would make my computer freeze when I wanted to switch for Xorg. Uninstalling it made it work.

I still had a few issues with my laptop so I went on and looked the rest of the doc I had, so I added the following from https://gist.github.com/whizzzkid/37c0d365f1c7aa555885d102ec61c048

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"'
sudo update-grub2
```

That fixed an issue, I had when I rebooted my machine. My laptop would freeze on boot!

That didn't fix my problem with Bumblebee though!

So I went on the ArchWiki to see what could be achieved and noticed that bumblebee seemed to be used by other user.

So I found that gist: https://gist.github.com/parasquid/5cbfb9a8f4159b546ab8b2ef2328d942, from which I saw the following code:

### configure required kernel parameter (https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/148)

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
change this parameter to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"
sudo update-grub2
```

I rebooted and everything worked!

I hope it will helps other people having the same problem I had!